# entities not saved consistently with google datastore put

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, put

I have a very simple bit of code where I add some entities to the datastore.

```
    public final class storageUtil {

    private static DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();  

    public static Iterable<Entity> getAllEntities(String kind) {
        Query q = new Query(kind);
        PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
        return pq.asIterable();
    }

    public static void putEntity(Entity entity) {
        datastore.put(entity);
    }


}
```

If I call putEntity(myEntity) and then getAllEntities(myKind), the newly put entity, will only show up in the returned list 2 out of 3 times.

If I call datastore.get(myKey) right after put, it will always return the newly put entry.

Can any one give me a clue as to what is going on?

Comment: Any chance that multiple threads, i.e. a racing condition, might be involved? I don't know Google DataStore but maybe the added entity is not flushed yet and thus not returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

what kind of DataStore are you using?
is this a high replication (default) datastore?
are you testing against the real server (not the dev?)
if so, this behaviour is somewhat expected because of the "eventually consistent" behavior.

[Using the High Replication Datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/hr/overview.html)

is where you should start looking for the ways around this

Comment: it's the high replication, but in a dev envirionment - not on the real server.

Comment: I could live with the inconsistencies, when saving in the application, since I am maintaining a local list anyway, but when restarting the app, only some of the entities get loaded... the rest has just disappeared.

Comment: I updated my application to use entity groups, and this seems to fix the inconsistency (i.e. fetching the group as a list includes all the expected entities), but still when I restart, only a fraction of the saved entities are loaded. Is this an issue of the local dev datastore, or can I expect the issue to persist when deploying to a real server?

Comment: my experience with the dev datastore, is that it is quite similar to the real one (beside performance), so this issue seems like a real issue, and not an issue with the dev environment

Answer (score 0):

Put your entities into the datastore using transactions, [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html) you will find an example.